# Ubuntu Mate 15.10 won't boot after installation

Tags: boot

The installation went perfectly but after restart I am brought back to the initial black screen that says:

> Try Linux without installation, Check disk for defects, and Install Linux, ect.

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/380067) answer, point #13.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are rebooting with the install USB or CD inserted. Remove the USB drive and then restart.